# How to write with 2+ parameters function in point-free style

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, pointfree

I'm trying to implement this pointful function

```
const getItem = (items, id) => items.find(item => item.id === id);
```

in point-free style using ramda.js.

When i use something like this:

```
const getItem = find(propEq('id'));
```

the first parameter `items` will  be passed to `find` function, but we will lose 2nd `id` parameter.

The question is, how to implement `getItem` function in point-free style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are free to change the order of arguments of the function, [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) is a simple solution:

```js
const getItemById = R.useWith(
  R.find,
  [R.propEq('id')]
);

console.log(
  getItemById(
    'b',
    [{ id: 'a' }, { id: 'b' }]
  )
);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And if you want to keep the original parameter order, you can modify this to `R.useWith(R.flip(R.find), [R.identity, R.propEq('id')])`.  But at this point, the lambda is probably cleaner.